# Outlook addin delay during load using add-in express

Tags: outlook, delay, add-in, outlook-addin

I have created an outlook addin using add-in express.
This is a COM Addin.
There is a time delay of about 35 seconds while the custom addin loads to Outlook's memory, initially thought this might be due to the code inside, but when i commented the code in AddinModule() i.e. the constructor, it still takes 35 seconds.
While i tried to analyze further in the log file, i could see, there is no log for this duration, log details below
"
00:18:46 3880 4572 The 'shadow copy' is enabled.
00:18:46 3880 4572 Creating a new application domain.
00:18:46 3880 4572 Success.
00:19:21 3880 4572 Unwrapping the managed class.
00:19:21 3880 4572 Success.
"
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something has to be running to cause such a delay; the ADXLoader should be quite fast.  What other components do you have on the AddinModule designer?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be upgrading the .NET version.

I updated my framework to 4.5. This is also suggested by add-in express.
There was an improvement of around 25 seconds, which is a huge difference.

Meanwhile on the code side, I got a few lines of code changed to ensure everything loads *asynchronously*.